# require cycle: src\components\Login\Login.tsx -> src\components\Login\index.ts -> src\components\Login\Login.tsx

Tags: react-native, expo

What I am doing wrong and why I get the error message:

```
Require cycle: src\components\Login\Login.tsx -> src\components\Login\index.ts -> src\components\Login\Login.tsx

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
```

Login:

```
const Login = () => {
 ...
};

export default Login;
```

Styles:

```
export const s = StyleSheet.create({...})
```

Model.ts

```
interface ILogin {
 test: boolean;
}
```

index.ts

```
import Login from "./Login";
import { ILogin } from "./Model";
import { s } from './Style';

export {
  Login,
  ILogin,
  s
};
```

can anyone pls help me to solve this issue ?

€: my imports in login:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from '../Button';
import { Input } from '../Input';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import LottoView from 'lottie-react-native';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Feather from '@expo/vector-icons/Feather';
import { InputStyles } from '../Input';
import { ButtonStyles } from '../Button';
import { globalStyles } from '../../shared/GlobalStyles';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { ILogin } from './Model';
import { s } from './Style';
```

Comment: What are your `import`s in *Login.tsx*?

Comment: @Janik look at my code I edited it

Comment: are these all? My guess would be there is one `import … from './'` hiding somewhere.

Comment: yes you are right there were in my auth file, but one Question, if I type Login, then I can choose Login from login.tsx component not from index also there is no autocomplete of index, why?

Comment: I’m sorry, I can’t tell you why your autocompletion behaves like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cycle means your *login.tsx* imports something from *index.tsx*/`./`, which in turn imports your *login.tsx* again. Therefore your *login.tsx* kind of depends on itself and to resolve the cycle, you should replace the `import … from './'` through explicitly importing the desired file instead.